OpenSSL unable to sign data In Firebase JWT sign in PHP
We are trying to send push notifications in PHP, but we are getting this error:

[queue.ERROR] [FBM_ERROR] OpenSSL unable to sign data {"trace":["#0 /var/www/html/sites/mysite.com/release-4.10.4/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php(196): Firebase\JWT
JWT::sign

In my local, it's working with the SSL library 3.1.4, but in our site, it's 1.0.2K. I don't know whether it's because of SSL library version or not.

Local openSSL library version 3.1.4
Our site openSSL library version 1.0.2k


Ensure that the algorithm you are using for signing data is supported by the OpenSSL version on your server. OpenSSL 1.0.2k may not support some of the algorithms that OpenSSL 3.1.4 does. If the algorithm is not supported, you might need to update the OpenSSL version on your server.
